# How to preserve value of property with max id from each group of record?

Tags: javascript

In my regions array there are 3 records with selected property as true i.e `14.3,14.2,11.1`.

I am trying to set selected property to false for all lower version for each of the part whose selected property is true.

For example: 14.3 and 14.2 are selected and id of 14.3 is greater than 14.2 so for part = 30,selected property of 14.2 should be set to false as because it is lower version for part =30 from selected 14.3 and 14.2.

If I talk about 11.1,higher version would be 11.1 only because 11.2 which is higher that 11.1 is not selected so selected property of 11.1 will remains true only.

**Expected Output :**

```
var regions = [
                 {
                     "id": 77,
                     "selected": false,
                     "part": 33,
                     "name": "16.1", 
                 },
                {
                    "id": 76,
                    "part": 30,
                    "selected": true,
                    "name": "14.3",
                },
                {
                    "id": 71,
                    "part": 30,
                    "selected": false,
                    "name": "14.2",
                },
                {
                    "id": 70,
                    "part": 31,
                    "selected": false,
                    "name": "15.1",
                },
                {
                     "id": 54,
                     "part": 25,
                     "selected": false,
                     "name": "11.2",
                 }
                 ,
                 {
                     "id": 53,
                     "part": 25,
                     "selected": true,
                     "name": "11.1",
                 }
            ];
```

So for each part I am not getting how to preserve selected property to true for max id.

```js
var regions = [
                 {
                     "id": 77,
                     "selected": false,
                     "part": 33,
                     "name": "16.1", 
                 },
                {
                    "id": 76,
                    "part": 30,
                    "selected": true,
                    "name": "14.3",
                },
                {
                    "id": 71,
                    "part": 30,
                    "selected": true,
                    "name": "14.2",
                },
                {
                    "id": 70,
                    "part": 31,
                    "selected": false,
                    "name": "15.1",
                },
                {
                     "id": 54,
                     "part": 25,
                     "selected": false,
                     "name": "11.2",
                 }
                 ,
                 {
                     "id": 53,
                     "part": 25,
                     "selected": true,
                     "name": "11.1",
                 }
            ];
             var obj = { "id": 70,"part": 31, "selected": true,"name": "15.1" };
            
            for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
          if ((regions[i].part != obj.part
                        && regions[i].selected))
           {
                  regions[i].selected = false; //this set 14.3 and 11.1 selected to false.
           }
 }
 
 console.log(regions)
```

Comment: Your logic is really not clear

Comment: @Weedoze:Can you please tell me what part is not clear??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Array methods like `reduce` (to build a map from `part`s to maximum selected `id`) and `forEach` (to update the `selected` values of each region depending on whether it has the maximum `id`).

```js
var regions = [{
    "id": 77,
    "selected": false,
    "part": 33,
    "name": "16.1",
  },
  {
    "id": 76,
    "part": 30,
    "selected": true,
    "name": "14.3",
  },
  {
    "id": 71,
    "part": 30,
    "selected": true,
    "name": "14.2",
  },
  {
    "id": 70,
    "part": 31,
    "selected": false,
    "name": "15.1",
  },
  {
    "id": 54,
    "part": 25,
    "selected": false,
    "name": "11.2",
  },
  {
    "id": 53,
    "part": 25,
    "selected": true,
    "name": "11.1",
  }
]

var map = regions.reduce(function (map, e) {
  if (e.selected) map[e.part] = Math.max(map[e.part] || 0, e.id)
  return map
}, {})

console.log(map)

regions.forEach(function (e) {
  if (e.part in map) e.selected = e.id === map[e.part]
})

console.log(regions)
```

Comment: This worked.Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate through the array twice:

```
var maxes = {};

// keep track of the max value associated with each id
for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
    var id = regions[i].part;
    if (typeof maxes[id] === 'undefined')
        maxes[id] = +regions[i].name;
    else maxes[id] = Math.max(maxes[id], +regions[i].name);
}

// set the max to be true and all others to be false
for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
    if (+regions[i].name === maxes[regions[i].part])
        regions[i].selected = true;
    else
        regions[i].selected = false;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to optimize your answer to work with single loop??

Comment: Not really. You have to know the maxes for each part, and you can't do so until you've reached the end of the array.

Comment: maxes should be array but you have taken as object

Comment: Nope, it's supposed to be an object (so you can have named keys and values). It just happens to be that the key names are numbers, but they don't have to be.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.Thank you so much and please keep helping like this :)